# Prevent HTML5 video loading on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, html, video, html5-video

I'd like to load a video to play on desktops and tablets, but prevent it from loading on iPhones because it's just a graphical element.

Here's my code:

```
<video width="980" height="400" poster="/poster.jpg" autoplay loop>
 <source src="/images/front.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="/images/front.webm" type="video/webm">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

How can I tell iPhones to not load the video but just display the poster frame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<script>
var videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    videoElement.parentNode.removeChild(videoElement);
    videoElement.pause();
}
</script>
```

This assumes you only have one `video` element on the page.

Also, be sure to put the JavaScript before the closing `body` element or put it in an external JavaScript file.